# Add Android Feature

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, navigation-drawer

[image]

I am new to android development. I want to implement something like this image shown that whenever image is clicked on action bar, a pop up type of thing is shown. I want to know what feature of android is this and how can it be implemented.

Comment: It is called `Navigation Drawer`. [Here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) is a tutorial.

Comment: You can find an sample by creating a new project in Android studio.

Comment: thanks Egor N for the help :) . It was exactly I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Navigation Drawer pattern is officially described in the Android documentation!

[image]

Check out the following links:

1. Design docs can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html).
2. Developer docs can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).